# Canon: Dark Jedi/Sith Identity Crisis

Tags: star-wars, sith

Although the distinction between Dark Jedi and Sith is clear in Legends, the new canon version has redefined some critical underlying points.

In Legends, the Sith are considered to be the order of Dark Jedi who called Korriban their home and iconic birthplace. The early history is what defined their identity, however, particularly in the native Sith being their namesake, and the discovery of dark side knowledge while in isolation from the Republic that is inaccessible to normal Dark Jedi.

I'm still getting familiar with the changes made in the new canon, and I notice that [Dark Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi) don't have their own canon tab in Wookieepedia, so I have some questions:

1) Is this history still valid in canon?

2) If the above is no longer canon, then is there still such a thing as Dark Jedi, or is Sith the new catch-all name for dark side Force users?

3) If Sith in canon are still (technically) a subset of all Dark Jedi as they were in Legends, and the old distinction is no longer canon, then what separates them today?

Comment: FYI: Wookiepedia isn't canon. Having no tab doesn't **necessarily** imply something is or isn't canon, merely that nobody chose to go look into new canon for that specific detail yet. (it can, of course, also imply that the new canon didn't mention them yet).

Answer (score 3):

Right now the only qualifications we have for Sith in Canon are

1. An order originating on Korriban/Moraband: **Per TCW S6**
2. Adherents of the Dark Side
3. "Think inwardly; only of themselves." (Debatable, as this is Anakin parroting Jedi propaganda)
4. Follow the Rule of 2 since Darth Bane: **Again, TCW S6**

So while the distinction isn't nearly as hard and fast as it was in Legends, it's still there. Ventress is definitely not a Sith (She is described in the preview for *Dark Disciple* as a "One time Sith Acolyte"), but she is a dark sider. I"m not sure that the exact phrase "Dark Jedi," has been used in Canon yet, but there is a definite distinction between "Generic Dark Side Force User," and "Sith."

In addition, as DVK pointed out in his comment, there are other canon dark side traditions like the Nightsisters that don't fall under the banner of either Dark Jedi or Sith. The New Canon just hasn't been fleshed out enough yet to be able to draw concrete lines between some of these orders other than by name and arbitrary geographical differences (eg. Nightsisters are from Dathomir, Sith are the heritage of Korriban, etc).

In terms of philosophy, most of these orders are not yet built up in Canon, so while there is general support for a distinction between "Generic Dark Side Force User/Dark Jedi" and some of the more established Dark Side traditions like the Nightsisters and Sith.

I haven't read *Lords of the Sith* yet, but it's possible there will be some clarification in that and the upcoming *Dark Disciple* novel.

Comment: There are also other Dark Side users, e.g. Dathomir Sisters

Comment: Also to point out the sith only know extremes (another jedi propaganda by Obi Wan in Episode 3)